# How does special relativity plays in how changing magnetic fields lead to electric fields and how changing electric fields lead to magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism

I understand that special relativity is what help creates a magnetic field in currents. But what I don't understand is how this plays into how changing magnetic fields lead to electric fields and how changing electric fields lead to magnetic fields or if special relativity even plays into this. If anyone can clear up my misunderstandings, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0&t=2s&pp=ygUbdmVyaXRhc2l1bSBlbGVjdHJvbWFnbmV0aXNt) might be relevant

Comment: "I understand that special relativity is what help creates a magnetic field in currents." - I don't, can you elaborate please?

Comment: I've been told that when current flows through a wire, the electrons contract due to special relativity. This leads to a charge imbalance for moving electrons, essentially creating an electric field for moving electrons.